# How to set y axis minimum value Swift 3

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am trying to set a minimum y-axis value of 300 in swift 3 using the following code:

In viewDidLoad:

```
    barChartView.noDataText = "No information available."
    barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bothSided
    barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.5, yAxisDuration: 1.5)
    let ll = ChartLimitLine(limit: 300, label: "Target")
    barChartView.rightAxis.addLimitLine(ll)
    barChartView.chartDescription?.enabled = false
    barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 300;
    updateChartWithData(dataPoints: stringOfDate, values: totalNumber)




 func updateChartWithData(dataPoints: [String], values: [Int]) {
    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
    for i in 0..<values.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(values[i]))
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }
    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Total Number")
    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    barChartView.data = chartData
}
```

However when I use this code the minimum does not set to 300 and the bars in my bar chart no longer display.

Comment: Can you show more of your code please?

Comment: I've added more code, hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

If I set

barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0

I get: 
[image]

Then if I set:

barChartView.leftAxis.axisMinimum = 13

I get:
[image]

In the second graph all the bars with value lower than 13 are hidden. You didn´t show the data points in your code, but I think they must all be lower than 300 and that´s why they are hidden.

Comment: Did the answer help you? I am happy to help if you are still trying to solve the problem

Comment: Yes thanks for the response. How do I set a value for the y-axis to 300 then? so the axis goes up to a minimum of 300 but all the bars are shown regardless of number?

Comment: I don´t understand what you want to accomplish, can you show a picture to explain what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

We can not fix the min y position of the bar and we also face this problem when minimum value is very low and maximum value is very height then y position of the bar at minimum value goes down so i have found this solution that we have to mapping the value in small range like we have minimum value 1 and maximum value 100000 then map the value in range 1 to 5.

Formula for mapping in range:

```
// to convert in to the range of 1 to 5
private func convertRange(value:CGFloat) -> Int{
    let newStart:CGFloat = 1.0
    let newEnd:CGFloat   = 5.0
    let originalStart:CGFloat = CGFloat(viewModel.offerMin)
    let originalEnd:CGFloat   = CGFloat(viewModel.offerMax)
    let scale = (newEnd - newStart) / (originalEnd - originalStart);
    return Int((newStart + ((value - originalStart) * scale)));
}
```